# Знак после слова «смотри»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, двоеточие

Какой знак препинания вы поставили бы на месте вопроса?

*– Ахаха! – рассмеялся Николя. – Смотри (?) даже Жюль в шоке! Ахаха! – хохотал он.*

У автора запятая. Я поставила бы двоеточие, но сомневаюсь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Думаю, что использование запятой в этом предложении вполне корректно.
*— Ахаха! — рассмеялся Николя. — Смотри, даже Жюль в шоке! Ахаха! — хохотал он.*

Здесь слово "смотри" выступает в роли междометия:
[смотреть](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C) — **смотри; смотрите, *в зн. межд.*** **2.** Выражает удивление. *Смотри, как разоделся! Смотрите, какой храбрый!*

***Смотри,** даже трость стала как будто тяжелее* (Дмитрий Емец. Таня Гроттер и колодец Посейдона).

*— Ты озябла, что ли? — спросил Николай Григорьевич. — **Смотри,** даже зубами стучишь...* (Ю. В. Трифонов. Исчезновение).

Comment: Спасибо, Римма!

Answer (score 1):

Не могу писать комментарии, поэтому напишу здесь. Первый ответ неправильный в том отношении, что ‟смотри” тут междометье (но правильный в том, что запятая). ‟Смотри” является междометьем, когда обозначает что-то вроде удивления и заменяется ‟о” или ‟ишь ты”: ‟О как разоделся!”, ‟Ишь ты как разоделся!”, ‟О какой храбрый!”, ‟Ишь ты какой храбрый!”.

Но слово ‟смотри” может использоваться как обычное повеление со значением ‟обрати внимание”, такое значение и есть в предложении в вопросе, а также во многих других предложениях.

Comment: Спасибо, Jim Korbett!